# Unable to load ASP.NET Core web app in tanzu (prev PCF)

Tags: .net-core, buildpack, tanzu-application-service

I am uploading/publishing an ASP.NET Core web app on tanzu platform using below command on powershell command line.

```
cf push -f .\manifest-Dev.yml
```

The manifest-Dev contains these details:

[image]

But I am getting this error:

[image]

Could someone help me resolve this error? Thanks and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error. The reason was .NET core version on my system was different than provided in the buildpack.yml  file. As i changed from

```
dotnet-core:
  sdk: 3.1.0
```

to

```
dotnet-core:
  sdk: 6.0.23
```

it worked fine.